# Flutter HTML: How can I get rid off of empty space that come with height of the video?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-html

I am using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/versions/3.0.0-beta.2). I am fetching a video that has specific height which I made smaller and I got empty space in the bottom.

Here's how I'm fetching HTML data:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xijoARJgwe0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And here's how I changed it's style in Flutter:

```
"iframe": Style(
                      height: Height(200),
                      display: Display.block,
                      padding: HtmlPaddings.zero,
                      margin: Margins(
                        right: Margin.zero(),
                        left: Margin.zero(),
                        bottom: Margin.zero(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

And here's what I'm having:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgueV.png)

I need to get rid off this empty space. Please help.